# Can I share iOS Realm Databases with App Groups?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, ios-app-group

Can I share iOS Realm Databases with App Groups? If yes, how? If not, how can I share my Realm Database to my other apps?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To share Realms between apps in the same iOS app group, you'll need to specify a common location for the Realm:

```
let fileURL = FileManager.default
    .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.io.realm.app_group")!
    .appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: fileURL)
let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
```

Comment: Really Good Answer.